# How to trigger Hibernate PostUpdateEventListener when using javax.persistence.Query.executeUpdate()

Tags: hibernate, jpa, event-listener, post-update

I have a class that implements PostUpdateEventListener, like this:

```
public class MyListener implements PostUpdateEventListener {

        @Override
        public void onPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent event) {}
}
```

When I try something like the code below, the record is updated but my listener is not called:

```
getEntityManager().createQuery("update MyObject set myAttribute = null where idMyObject in (:ids)")
.setParameter("ids", idsList)
.executeUpdate();
getEntityManager().flush();
```

When I use the variant below, it got called:

```
myObject.setMyAttribute(null);
getEntityManager.merge(myObject);
getEntityManager.flush();
```

As I have a lot of objects to update, a bulk update makes sense, but I need to keep the listener call.

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Thank you!